# Am I able to set "Default Web Site"'s properties through a child website's web.config file? (IIS6)

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-6, isapi-rewrite

I am experiencing the following issue under IIS6. I understand the issue completely, I am just looking for the best solution.

I have the following:

- Default Web Site

  - apiservices
  - ourwebsite

The website 'apiservices' is running under .NET Framework v2.0 still.
The website 'ourwebsite' is running under .NET Framework v4.0 using MVC3.

A sweet new feature introduced in .NET 4.0, Extensionless URL handling, is causing us some issues because of our mixed .NET framework versions.

If I go to:

- 'ourwebsite' -> right click -> properties -> virtual directory tab -> configuration. I see that there exists a wildcard application mapping to .NET Framework v4.0 aspnet_isapi.dll. **This is correct, but not sufficient due to our setup.**
- 'apiservices' -> right click -> properties -> virtual directory tab -> configuration. I see that there exists a wildcard application mapping to .NET Framework **v2.0** aspnet_isapi.dll **This is correct for our setup AND must not be set to 4.0 or it will break.**

Now, here is the error introduced due to microsoft's changes: **Because the ASP.NET v4.0 Application does not have its wildcard mapping defined at the root level, Default Web Site, PageMethods inside of our application get improperly routed and 404.**

The crazy part? If I go to:

- 'Default Web Site' -> right click -> properties -> 'Home Directory' tab -> configuration. And then, from here, add .NET Framework v4.0 to my Wildcard application maps.
- I click OK. I am prompted to indicate which children websites I wish to apply these changes to because they both define their own wildcard application mappings. **I indicate here that I only wish to apply this wildcard mapping to 'ourwebsite' and not 'apiservices'**

Applying this change resolves our issue.

Now, I am wondering, how do I go about setting this? Is this the job of the web.config file -- can it control upper-level settings like this? Or is it the job of a custom action of our installer?

EDIT: It looks like I need to do this using WIX. Currently, I have the code below to set the wildcard map at the child level. I am exploring ways of setting it at the root level without overwriting 'apiservices' wildcard mapping:

```
<iis:WebVirtualDir Id="CSWebVirtualDir" Alias="[TARGETCSWEBVDIR]" Directory="CABLESOLVEWEBDIR" WebSite="DefaultWebSite">
    <iis:WebApplication Id="CSWebApplication" Name="[TARGETCSWEBVDIR]" AllowSessions="yes" ParentPaths="yes" ScriptTimeout="900" SessionTimeout="60" WebAppPool="CSWebAppPool" ClientDebugging="no" ServerDebugging="no" Isolation="medium">
        <iis:WebApplicationExtension Executable="[FRAMEWORKROOT]v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" CheckPath="no" Script="yes" Verbs="GET,HEAD,POST" />
    </iis:WebApplication>
    <iis:MimeMap Id="MIMEXAP" Type="application/x-silverlight-app" Extension=".xap" />
    <iis:MimeMap Id="MIMEXAML" Type="application/xaml+xml" Extension=".xaml" />
</iis:WebVirtualDir>

<iis:WebVirtualDir Id="CSWebAPIVirtualDir" Alias="[TARGETCSWEBAPIVDIR]" Directory="CABLESOLVEWEBAPIDIR" DirProperties="CSWebAPIVirtualDirProperties" WebSite="DefaultWebSite">
    <iis:WebApplication Id="CSWebAPIApplication" Name="[TARGETCSWEBAPIVDIR]" ParentPaths="yes" AllowSessions="yes" ScriptTimeout="900" SessionTimeout="60" WebAppPool="CSWebAPIAppPool" ClientDebugging="no" ServerDebugging="no" Isolation="medium">
        <iis:WebApplicationExtension Executable="[FRAMEWORKROOT]v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" CheckPath="no" Script="yes" Verbs="GET,HEAD,POST" />
    </iis:WebApplication>
</iis:WebVirtualDir>
```

Comment: Are both Websites running under the same Application Pool in IIS?

Comment: No, they have separate application pools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our solution was to add these steps to our install guide. I was unable to determine a way of simply modifying the Default Web Site.